# plugin to go to last line

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I want to create plugin for `sublime text 3` which can move to last line of opened file. Now I can go to line by its number:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class prompt_goto_lineCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):

    def run(self):
        self.window.show_input_panel("Goto Line:", "", self.on_done, None, None)
        pass

    def on_done(self, text):
        try:
            line = int(text)
            if self.window.active_view():
                self.window.active_view().run_command("goto_line", {"line": line} )
        except ValueError:
            pass

class go_to_lineCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit, line):
        # Convert from 1 based to a 0 based line number
        line = int(line) - 1

        # Negative line numbers count from the end of the buffer
        if line < 0:
            lines, _ = self.view.rowcol(self.view.size())
            line = lines + line + 1

        pt = self.view.text_point(line, 0)

        self.view.sel().clear()
        self.view.sel().add(sublime.Region(pt))

        self.view.show(pt)
```

But I don't know number of last row. How to get it from object `sublime_plugin.WindowCommand`? Or maybe another way to move cursor to last row without getting its number? I tried to find in [api documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html)? But no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codes in `go_to_lineCommand` has already showed you how to calculate the last line number. `self.view.size()` returns the number of character in the file. So `self.view.rowcol(self.view.size())` return row and column number of last `point` in document. By the way, AFAIK, a `point` is like an index in array.

So you can go to last line by calculate the last line number or just use **0** as the line number.

```
view.run_command("go_to_line", {'line':'0'})
```

Comment: In case you landed here trying to make this work on ST3, the name of the command is `goto_line`.

Answer (score 3):

For those that aren't looking to build a plug-in specifically and are using Sublime Text 3, you might be interested to learn the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>end</kbd>. I'm not quite sure if it exists for Sublime Text 2, aswell.

As you're specificly looking to build a plugin, you might do something like the build-in Sublime Text 3 command, as alternative to the `go_to_line` solution.

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eof", "extend": false} }`